Seeding data when it has relationship
I need to create foreach entity its own seed class.
The problem becomes when the is some hierarchy of entities, like one entity has a relation with another, second has relation with third and so on.
For example I have 4 entities:
Entity1

Id
Name

Entity2

Id
Name

Entity3

Id
Entity1Id
Entity2Id

Entity4

Id
Entity3Id

When I seed entity1 and entity2, I also create two enums each for entity. This enum will contain id of entity.
While seeding entity3, I am getting all values from 1st and 2st enum and just use loop to seed this Entity1Id and Entity2Id properties in Entity3 entity.
For this moment everything is great.
But the problem is Entity4 uses Entity3Id which I can't specify. For this entity I can not create enum that will hold its id so I can use it for Entity3Id in Entity4 entity.
How can I solve this problem?
I just need to somehow take all id from Entity3 and set Entity3Id property in Entity4 entity.

Do you use has HasData aks model seed data, or use custom seeding logic?

i am using just add method from db context. can use HasData also but it will not resolve the issue

Please turn the question into a [mre]. This can't be answered without seeing the actual code.

In your case, Entity3 have relationship with Entity4. You can add directly to the navigation property of Entity3.
I.e:
// `Entity3` have one to many relationship with `Entity4`
entity3.Entities4.Add(entity4);
dbContext.Add(entity3);
await dbContext.SaveChangeAsync();


yea. i know about that kind of implementation. but as i said i dont want to create in one seed file both entity and entity 4 objects

each seed class should contain only one entity type. So Entity3Seed should seed only entity3 data. and Entity4Seed should seed only entity4 data.
